# google summary sheets row differ greater than value

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets with data like:

```
A  B  C
1  2  x1
2  3  X2
3  5  x3
```

I would like to generate a summary sheets say delta between rows great than 2.

So differ looks like (maybe no need show to user):

```
A  B  C
NA NA  x1
1  1   x2
1  2   x3
```

valid output:

```
A  B  C
1   2  x3
```

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This is so we will be able to understand the issue better.

Comment: You expected output doesn't make sense. It should `3  5  x3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
=query(
   map(A3:A,B3:B,C3:C,lambda(A,B,C,
    {
      indirect("A"&row(A))-indirect("A"&row(A)-1),
      indirect("B"&row(B))-indirect("B"&row(B)-1),
      C
    })
),"select * where Col2>1 or Col1>1")
```

I used `MAP / LAMBDA` to create the differ tab.
`INDIRECT` to calculate each delta `value(n) - value(n-1)`.
And to filter all the differ tab lines, I used a `QUERY`.